# Open a Workbook with XLWINGS without making it visible

Tags: python, excel, visibility, xlwings

I am starting to use XLWings (not that I like Excel, at all, but it is something I HAVE TO do). The thing is that I cannot find the way to make Python open a Workbook without showing it.

It seems the constructor for Workbooks in the old XLWings 0.6.4 was xlwings.Workbook, and one of the arguments was a flag 'app_visible' (see http://docs.xlwings.org/en/v0.6.4/api.html).

However, in the new v0.9.2 Workbook has been replaced by Book, and Book does not have any such flag (http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html). The App object does have it, and I thought that was the way to go. So I coded:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
filename = os.path.join(PATH_EXCEL_SAMPLES, r"rangosConDatos_sample01.xls")
book = xw.Book(filename)
# Do stuff with the info in the book
book.close()  # Ya puedo cerrar el libro.
app.kill()
```

But, regretably, when

```
book = xw.Book(filename)
```

is executed the 'visible' attribute of app suddenly becomes True, and the book is shown. I do not know if this is a desired feature or an unexpected behaviour. Anyway, any ideas how should I do it?

Comment: Right now I would say it's a bug. Does it work if you open the book like this? `app.books.open(filename)`

Comment: @Felix I tried, but it does exactly the same.

Comment: @ Felix I see you fixed it, thxs!

Comment: Yup, that was fixed with v0.9.3, thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since version 0.24.3, where [`with xw.App():`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api/app.html#app) is implemented, the idiomatic way is:

```
import xlwings as xw

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")

    # Do some stuff e.g.
    wb.sheets[0]["A1"].value = 12345

    wb.save("test.xlsx")
    wb.close()
```

The advantage of this is that there won't be any hidden excel processes left over in the background, if you use a hidden instance and your code fails.

Comment: Just a small comment: if you don't change the name of the file, `book.save()` is enough.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my working code fragment:

```
    import xlwings

    excel_app = xlwings.App(visible=False)
    excel_book = excel_app.books.open('PATH_TO_YOUR_XLSX_FILE')
    excel_book.save()
    excel_book.close()
    excel_app.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
book = xw.Book('PATH_TO_YOUR_XLSX_FILE')
sheet = book.sheets('sheetname')
df = sheet.range('A1:D10')
book.close()
app.quit()
```

#corrected typo

Answer (score 2):

You could try 'with open', for example

```
with open ("write.csv", "a", newline='') as file:  
    fields=['score', 'name']                       
    writer=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writerow({'score' : score, 'name' : username})

with open ("write.csv", "r") as file:
    sortlist=[]
    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for i in reader:
        sortlist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
readsheet = xw.Book('FILE_PATH').sheets['Sheet1']
df = pd.DataFrame(readsheet.range('A1', 'Z99').value)
```