# Open a workbook in xlwings without making it visible

Tags: python, excel, visibility, xlwings

I am having the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995281/open-a-workbook-with-xlwings-without-making-it-visible), according to the comments of this post this issue was resolved in v0.9.3.

My versions are:

- xlwings: v0.11.4
- macOS: v10.13.2
- python: v3.6.2
- Excel for Mac: v15.41

I have attempted the app.books.open(filename) workaround but it makes no difference. Despite being updated past v0.9.3 I'm still unable to open a workbook in headless mode.

Is anyone able to suggest any workarounds or possible bugs?
Thank you.

Comment: It's a known limitation on Mac, see https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/652

Comment: this will be solved with xlwings v0.20.6