# XLwings - Can't get Excel application to quit even with kill() method

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have searched and cannot seem to find the answer to my issue. I’m hoping someone can help.

Here is a slimmed down version of my code. I have it within a unit test `TestCase` class. I open three books, one of which is an `xlsm` file (`wb2`), do some processing, and then save the `wb2` file with another name and close all three workbooks.

What's happening is that all three workbooks are closing, but there still remains an instance of Excel open. Like, an empty shell with nothing in it. I searched and found the `kill()` method, but that is not killing it (whether I use `self.xw.App().kill()` or just `xw.App().kill())`. Also, I print out all of the open apps and it returns an empty list. So, I don't know what this instance remaining is all about and why it's not getting killed. BTW, I am using Excel 365. Thanks in advance.

```py
import xlwings as xw

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_xltest(self):     

        #Open 3 separate workbooks
        self.wb1 = xw.Book(workbook1)
        self.wb2 = xw.Book(workbook2)
        self.wb3 = xw.Book(workbook3)

        #Do some processing here

    def tearDown(self):            
        self.wb1.close()
        self.wb2.save(self.newDirectoryPath)
        self.wb2.close()
        self.wb3.close()

        print (xw.apps)
        self.xw.App().kill()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: xlwings currently needs at least 1 workbook open to be able to talk to the application instance. So quit or kill your app before you close the last workbook.

Comment: Thank you.  I found this solution on another post and it worked like a charm.  app = xw.apps.active
        app.quit()

Comment: See also [with xw.App() as app:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70158361/13968392), which is in my opinion the simplest approach.